# Sending post data using html a tag

Tags: javascript, html, cakephp, postdata

I would like to send POST data using an html  tag.
I know that there is no way doing this unless i script.
However i tried , but couldn't get it to work.

```
<a class="test" onClick="assign()"><img src='<?php echo $accounts[$i]['Account']['image']; ?>' /> <?php echo $accounts[$i]['Account']['screen_name']; ?></a>
```

I tried using this:

```
function assign(){ 
            $.post("/Accounts/index", 
            { data: "test" 


            });
        }
```

and i also tried this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $(".test").click(function(){

                $.post("/accounts/index", 
                { data: "test"

                });
            });

        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060025/submit-a-form-when-click-on-a-hyperlink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(".test").click(function () {
    $.ajax({ url: 'http://.....your path...../accounts/index',
        data: {test:1},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            //your code
                 }
            }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to prevent the anchor's default click action by returning false like so:

```
<a class="test" onClick="assign(); return false;"> ...
```

or like so:

```
...
$(".test").click(function(){
    ...
    return false;
});
```