# Binding click handler to dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

When I create a new link dynamically, I can't catch the click event

```
$("#div").html("<a href="#" id="new">new link</a>);

$("#new").click(function(e) { //doesn't catch
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('click');
}
```

How can I bind handlers to dynamic elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference the created element by ID because it hasn't been added to the DOM yet and jQuery searches the DOM for ID's. Instead save a reference to the element and attach the click to that.

```
var div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'div');
var link = $('<a>')
  .attr('href', '#')
  .attr('id', 'new')
  .on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('click');
  })
  .appendTo(div);
```

Comment: attachTo doesn't seems exist

Comment: That was supposed to say `appendTo`. fricken autocorrect.

Comment: it is not really direct and not well written but it is a way! Thank you!

Comment: Would you be interested to expand why you felt it wasn't well written? I'd be interested in learning a different perspective. As reference the above is a typical [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#JavaScript) ("There are many examples of JS libraries that use some variant of this: jQuery probably being the most well known.") Method chaining and the jQuery DSL is a well established and popular style to manage things like this. Composability offers a lot more flexibility and readability then sticking hacked up HTML strings in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this works fine for me: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bezdz8gu/)

You had a number of syntax errors in your original code.

```
$("#div").html("<a href='#' id='new'>new link</a>");
fixed quotes here ------^^^                      ^
fixed missing end quote here --------------------^

// works fine!
$("#new").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('click');
});
```

Comment: no my example was written too quick without editor , it is a real question

Comment: no, i made a mistake in my question but I am really trying to add item in DOM after loading

Comment: I'm not sure why that fiddle isn't working for you; it works perfectly for me. What browser are you using? You have two options: use `setTimeout` to run the click binding code a few milliseconds delayed (not great), or try Sukima's suggestion of building the element with jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

[You should try this post out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686905/sending-post-data-using-html-a-tag)

It looks like it will answer your question.

To sum it up, try

```
$(".test").click(function () {
$.ajax({ url: 'http://.....your path...../accounts/index',
    data: {test:1},
    type: 'post',
    success: function(output) {
        //your code
             }
        }); 
});
```

Comment: That is ajax and has nothing to do with clicking an element

Comment: I can see no connection between question and this answere